# Using JWT along with SwaggerUI Bundle for pre-authentication In angular 8

Tags: angular, swagger-ui, jwt

I'm trying to integrate SwaggerUiBundle in angular application. While getting the request from created url, I don't have to authorize it again & use the current JWT token which stored in localStorage to send along to use CRUD request in swagger.
I'm not able to store the token anywhere. I need some help regarding this issue. 
Thanks all.

```
ngOnInit() {

const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
  dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
  layout: 'BaseLayout',
  presets: [
    SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
    SwaggerUIBundle.SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
  ],
  url: url,
  docExpansion: 'none',
  operationsSorter: 'alpha',
  securityDefinitions: {
    JWT: {
      type: "apiKey",
      description: "",
      name: "Authorization",
      in: "header"
    }
  },
  // requestInterceptor: function(request){
  //   console.log('[Swagger] intercept try-it-out request');
  //   let currentUser = hInterceptor.userService.currentUserValue;
  //   var token = `Bearer ${currentUser.token}`
  //   request.headers.Authorization = token;
  //   return request;
  // }
  // requestInterceptor: function(request){
  //   var rq = new HttpRequest(
  //     "GET",
  //     request.url,
  //     request.body, {
  //     headers: new HttpHeaders(request.headers),
  //     responseType: request.responseType,
  //   })
  //   hInterceptor.intercept(rq, new HttpXhrBackend({ build: () => new XMLHttpRequest }));
  // }
  }
```

Comment: could you resolve it?